# Office add-ins not working on Safari with exchange 2016

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

We created an outlook add-in and we noticed that for quite a few months OWA does not load *any* add-ins in OWA calendar events in Safari browser. We tested on Safari on several MacOS systems and the result was the same. Below print screen when attempting to open Emojis, but we had the same result for any of the add-ins we have setup for the email account. We received feedback from our customers that the issue reproduces for them as well.

[image: Error in logon.aspx when attempting to open any outlook add-in]

UPDATE:

[image: Console log part1]

[image: Console log part 2]

Comment: Hi horymury, did face similar issue on other browsers as well? Also could you let us know if you're using the old or new version of outlook and share console details?

Comment: Updated my question with screen capture of the console.
The issue only happens on Safari, works fine on all other browsers.
No Javascript based add-in works, not even the built-in My templates add-in; the problem is not only with our add-in.
We use an on-premise Exchange 2016 server.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue regarding outlook add-ins not working on Safari. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point.

Comment: Is there a way for us to track when this will be fixed? Thank you.